# How to find overlapping tuples in a list and return overlapping tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I currently have a list with tuples in it.

```
overlap_list = [(10001656, 10001717), (700, 60000), (10001657, 10001718), (10001657, 10001716), (10031548, 10031643), (10031556, 10031656)]
```

I am wanting the following output:

```
new_list=[(10001656, 10001717),(10001657, 10001718),(10001657, 10001716),(10031548, 10031643), (10031556, 10031656)]
```

The numbers inside the tuples are starts and stop boundaries. I am wanting to find any tuples that overlap between the numbers.

I have tried this code that I found, that asked a similar question:

```
import itertools as ittools

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = ittools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

overlap_list = [(10001656, 10001717), (700, 60000), (10001657, 10001718), (10001657, 10001716), (10031548, 10031643), (10031556, 10031656)]
print([list(p) for k, p in it.groupby(pairwise(overlap_list), lambda x: x[0][0] < x[1][0] < x[0][1]) if k])
```

But this gives:

```
[[((10031548, 10031643), (10031556, 10031656))]]
```

I have looked at different solutions, but the problem that I am faced is that indexing by the position before doesn't seem to work.

How can I get the desired output? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by overlapping?

Comment: @DanielMesejo: E.g.: `(10001656, 10001717),(10001657, 10001718)`: See the tuples as a `range(start.value, end.value)`, therefore the second `start.value (10001657)` is within the `range` of the first tuple.

Comment: Your desired output appears to contain two different groups of overlapping tuples without altering the order of the original list, so does that mean you are just trying to filter out any tuples that do not overlap with any other tuple in the list? And you don't care about output order or grouping?

Comment: @benvc: Yes, you are correct I am wanting to find any tuples that have overlapping values within the list. I don't care about the order of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest - I don't really understand your code and the idea behind it and therefore cannot tell you why the result contains only a subset of the desired tuples.

However, I have a different approach which you might find interesting.
The main idea is to have a function which can test two tuples against overlapping.
This function is applied to all combinations of tuples in your `overlap_list`. If two overlap, they are added to a result list, which will afterwards contain duplicates, and therefore `list(set(result))` is applied in the end. *However, you can leave away the cast to list, as a set is ok as a result either imo...*

The idea of the test function is to simply sort the 4 values of two tuples to be tested and look at the sorting order (see [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)). If the first two indices are 0/1 or 2/3, the two tuples do not overlap.
In other words: tested against being `>1` they simply have to be unequal, i.e. not both True or False:

```
def overlap_test(tpl1, tpl2):
    import numpy as np
    a, b = np.argsort(tpl1 + tpl2)[:2] > 1
    return a != b
```

And here's the loop where the function is used:

```
import itertools as it
result = []
for test_tpl, sec_tpl in list(it.combinations(overlap_list, 2)):
    if overlap_test(test_tpl, sec_tpl):
        result.extend([test_tpl, sec_tpl])
result = list(set(result))

# [(10001657, 10001718),
#  (10031556, 10031656),
#  (10031548, 10031643),
#  (10001657, 10001716),
#  (10001656, 10001717)]
```

I'm still wondering if the loop couldn't be a little more efficient and in that way if perhaps also the need for `set` couldn't be optimized away - well, perhaps you find a better one.

---

***EDIT:***

Didn't really find sth very different so far, but a little improvement:

Same approach but using `set` right from the beginning:

```
def find_overlap_tuples_0(tpl_list):
    result = set()
    for test_tpl, sec_tpl in list(it.combinations(tpl_list, 2)):
        if overlap_test(test_tpl, sec_tpl):
            result.add(test_tpl)
            result.add(sec_tpl)
    return list(result)

# %timeit find_overlap_tuples_0(overlap_list)
# 178 µs ± 4.87 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

a little different, only based on permutations and grouping *(seems to be slightly faster)*:

```
def find_overlap_tuples_1(tpl_list):
    result = set()
    no_ovl = set()
    for a, grp in it.groupby(it.permutations(tpl_list, 2), lambda x: x[0]):
        for b in grp:
            if (a not in result) and (b[1] not in no_ovl):
                if overlap_test(*b):
                    result.add(b[0])
                    result.add(b[1])
                    break
                no_ovl.add(b[0])
    return list(result)

# %timeit find_overlap_tuples_1(overlap_list)
# 139 µs ± 1.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back. Thanks for the great suggestion on imputing two tuples. Your code works great!

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm glad if it helps. However, if you have - except clearly overlapping and non overlapping tuples - also _touching_ tuples, I mean tuples which share the same border, like `(2, 5)` and `(5, 7)`, this might lead to errors in this idea with `argsort`, simply because I don't know which order this command will create in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could just sort the list so that any overlapping starts and stops are adjacent and then just compare neighbors to determine whether or not any tuple needs to be filtered out due to non-overlapping (sort at the end of the code is not necessary, just makes it easier to see the overlapping neighbors in the print output).

```
l = [(10001656, 10001717), (700, 60000), (10001657, 10001718), (10001657, 10001716), (10031548, 10031643), (10031556, 10031656)]

l.sort()
overlap = set()
for a, b in zip(l, l[1:]):
    if a[1] >= b[0] and a[1] <= b[1]:
        overlap.add(a)
    if b[0] >= a[0] and b[0] <= a[1]:
        overlap.add(b)

overlap = sorted(overlap)        
print(overlap)
# [(10001657, 10001716), (10001657, 10001718), (10031548, 10031643), (10031556, 10031656)]
```